# Creating new address isn't working correctly

Tags: node.js, curl, bitcoin, coinbase-api, litecoin

I am following the documentation posted on the [Coinbase API Documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#create-address) page and had everything work the past few days. But I noticed that in the last 24-48 hours that creating New Addresses is no longer working.

I was using the node.js package [Coinbase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinbase) and thought that maybe something had changed on their end. So I attempted to do the request with "request" and then with curl from the command line.

The curl code below:

```
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/addresses \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -d '{"name": "New receive address"}'
```

Should return a JSON with a new address and the name of "New receive address", however it just returns the last unused address linked to my Coinbase.

I saw others were having a similar issue but I can't comment because my rep isn't high enough and that post was closed due to off-topic. :|

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the third party service you're using. Not really a good question for SO.

Comment: While I agree, this is where Coinbase API documentation links for support. I've filed a support ticket and tweeted to them, but this is pretty urgent and so while I know this isn't the best place. I'm hoping either someone knows a temp work around or can get the right eyes on the problem to fix it.

Comment: Try using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to do the same request and see if it works. If it does then you know it's the way you are using CURL. If it doesn't then you know either their API is having a problem or you are calling it incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah, I used ARC before curl to test. Again all the code was working before, something changed recently on their end for sure. It almost feels like they aren't getting it as a POST and just accepting it as a GET as that would always return the last created address.

I just hope their support pays attention and get's my tickets to the right people.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same behaviour with a small project I'm developing in c#. I'm not using any SDK, just old plain webrequests: same problem as yours.

Comment: It’s been fixed as of 10pm CST. No response from Coinbase on the issue or the fix. Status page never mentioned it and all emails/support tickets/tweets go in answered.

Answer (score 0):

it's about Bip44 gap limit when you create more than 20 unused addresses almost all wallets will stop generating new addresses until you use one of these previously generated addresses.

when you create a wallet, coinbase will watch only 20 generated addresses if you received a payment on address number 15, coinbase will watch 15 + 20 addresses and like that.

Bitcoin core not using Bip44 they're just creating address and watch it, so maybe it could be a good alternative.

Comment: I don’t think this was the case. I understand bip32 and  understand what you’re saying. But I run a service that uses Coinbase Oauth and it was happening to all accounts that were configued even new users that never had more than 3 addresses generated. As I mentioned in my comment on the 27th, everything started working again without any changes on my end.

Comment: Can you now generate more than 20 address? Sorry but I have no experience with Coinbase but there's no reason to start giving you old unused addresses. you should contact them to see the matter.

Coinbase seems to be creating address and watch it and they are not working with any Bip's

Comment: Yes, I can now generate as many as I want. I contacted them 3 different ways, opened tickets, called, tweeted, etc. Silence on their end.

Comment: Expect an answer after 4 months. as usual with Coinbase